# facebook php header redirect

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I have a simple `php` script that im using that just does a `simple header()` redirect to facebook's `sharer.php`, this is always producing a blank window - I can see the address bar but window is blank, works fine if i use another `URL` other then facebook.

```
header("Location: $fburl");
```

Any ideas here? I have tried `javascript window.location` also and it produces the same result, whats odd though is when I refresh the blank window in my `browser` it loads the page..

Comment: Have you tried enabling errors?

Comment: yeah - no errors, it just seems facebook is blocking this some how, like i said it works fine if i change the url to something other then facebook.

Comment: Can it be that facebook is sending you a blank page?

Comment: well yeah it has to be facebook because like i said any other url works fine. the facebook url DOES work if you refresh the blank page which confuses me even more.

Comment: What php version are you running?  Though I need to go to bed; maybe someone with better knowledge can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect should work,
please try the following I just tested and it works

```
$fburl = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.google.com';

header("Location: $fburl", true, 303);
```

Comment: 303 – See Other. Resource you are looking for can be found under different URL

Comment: The URL to share the link on FB is https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[your link]

Comment: this produces the same result - blank page (only with facebook's sharer.php) - now if i refresh that blank page it loads just fine

Comment: $fburl='http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' . $rootdircomb . 'index.html';

Comment: Would you mind posing the url here what you are trying to redirect to the FB share ?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://ninjascriptcreator.net/scripts/users/admin/833cc54744366852bdd1d4d2e8112382/index.html - the hash changes on each post (the dirs do exist as well) if its any help this all happens in a popup window.

Answer (score -1):

Try something in this manner .It will work surely..

```
<a style="float:right; margin-top:10px;" onClick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=*****8&link=<?php  echo $url_to_share;  ?>&picture=<?php echo $absolute_path_fb; ?>&description=<?php  echo $description;  ?>&redirect_uri=<?php  echo $url_to;  ?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">Share</a>
```